# Why do I need to log in again to join a new site?

Tags: support, feature-request, sign-up

I signed up for Stack Overflow from my Yahoo account. Then I went to Android Enthusiasts via *More Stack Exchange Communities*. I was asked to log in to join the site, then I was redirected to Yahoo, and then I had to click *Agree*. Why can't I join the site directly?

I am asking for a <kbd>Join Site</kbd> button at the top, so that I can directly join.

Comment: You may find this useful: [Why not have one login to all stack subdomains?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90565/why-not-have-one-login-to-all-stack-subdomains)

Comment: That helped @GeorgeCummins .I tried to flag as duplicate to close the question but it says the answer should be in meta stackoverflow.

Comment: You posted this on the Stack Overflow specific Meta, and Meta.Stackexchange.com is a separate site for *all* Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Looks like we can't close this based on a a meta.stackexchange question.  Not sure where the one completely unrelated close as dupe vote came from.